# Find the equation of the plane passing through $P(0,0,1)$ and containing $x=y=z$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, vectors

> Find the equation of the plane passing through $P(0,0,1)$ and
>   containing $x=y=z$
>
> **a**) y-z=0
>   **b**) x-z=0
>   **c**) z+x=1
>   **d**) x-y=0

**My attempt**:

I considered the point $P(0,0,1)$ for hypothesis and found two other points belonging to the line, for example, $(1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,0)$. So, solving the system:

$$\bigg \{
\begin{array}{rl}
x+y+z = 0 \\
z = 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

I get $(1,-1,0)$. Therefore, the answer could be **d**) x-y=0 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This looks fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is correct. I just suggest you to use other letters for the coordinates of the plane that you are looking for. For example you can write your equation as $ax+by+cz=0$. You found two equations that you wrote $x+y+z=0$ and $z=0$ and correspond to replace the points $(1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,1)$ in the equation. These should be $a+b+c=0$ and $c=0$ and the solutions are $c=0$, $a=-b$, which gives you the plane given by $x-y=0$ (or any multiple of this equation).

Comment: Nice hint, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. :-)